# Getting error like these in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

> TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

My code

```
@api.model
def action_purchase_order(self):
    rec= self.env['purchase.order'].create({
        'partner_id' : self.vendors,
        'store_id' : self.store_id,
        'purchase_order_type' : self.order_type,
        'date_order' : self.date_order,
        'product_id' : self.product_id,
        'date_planned' : self.date_order,
        'product_qty' : self.name,
        'brand_id' : self.brand_id,
        'product_id' : self.product_id,
        'part_number': self.part_number,
        'date_planned' : self.date_order,
        'product_qty' : self.quantity_no,

    })

    return rec
```

Access through button..

Comment: Please provide the xml code for your button. Also for a button I think you are supposed to use @api.multi

Comment: Thanks Philip for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `@api.multi` decorator for buttons actions, `api.model` is used when you only care about the model and not the field values it contains

```
@api.multi
def action_purchase_order(self):
    rec= self.env['purchase.order'].create({
        'partner_id' : self.vendors,
        'store_id' : self.store_id,
        'purchase_order_type' : self.order_type,
        'date_order' : self.date_order,
        'product_id' : self.product_id,
        'date_planned' : self.date_order,
        'product_qty' : self.name,
        'brand_id' : self.brand_id,
        'part_number': self.part_number,

    })

    return rec
```

from the [docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#module-openerp.api)

> openerp.api.multi(method)
>
> Decorate a record-style method where self is a recordset. The method
>   typically defines an operation on records.
>
> openerp.api.model(method)
>
> Decorate a record-style method where self is a recordset, but its
>   contents is not relevant, only the model is.